# How to concatenate two atoms/strings?

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to find out how to concatenate two atoms:

```
A = 'my ', 
B = 'atom',
```

How can I concatenate these two atoms so that the result is:

```
'my atom'
```

?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

For **atoms**:

```
?- atom_concat('my ', 'atom', X).
X = 'my atom'.
```

For **strings**:

```
:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars).
:- use_module(library(double_quotes)).

?- append("my ", "string", X).
X = "my string".
```

It took me a while to find the proper names. Maybe it will help others too.

Comment: You should use `string_concat/3` instead of `append/3` for strings, as explained in the answer of @KaitlinHipkin.

Comment: @morxa: I used sicstus prolog at that time. So a downvote is kind of harsh as there is no such function in the prolog distribution. :-)

Comment: the answer suggests this is the best way for all Prolog implementations, you never say it's for sicstus. Afaik, append/3 is not ISO, either. Setting double_quotes to chars may break applications. Even if you don't want to use `string_concat/3`, imho a combination of `atom_string/2` and `atom_concat/3` is better.

Comment: @morxa: @repeat user changed my question and removed `sicstus-prolog` tag and added `prolog` tag. ;-)

Answer (score 14):

Here is a simple solution that doesn't overcomplicate things.

To append **atoms**, use the [atom_concat/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=atom_concat/3) predicate:

```
A='my ', 
B='atom', 
atom_concat(A, B, FinalAtom).
```

To append **strings**, use the [string_concat/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=string_concat/3) predicate:

```
A="my ",     % single quotes also work
B="string", 
string_concat(A, B, FinalString)
```

*Both links go to pages on the official SWI-Prolog documentation website.*