# Prolog writeln with variables

Tags: prolog

I need to use writeln specifically in Prolog with a variable in it. What I am trying to make is an error that takes the first element of a list, and format does what I need almost perfectly, but again it specifically needs to be writeln.

I experimented for awhile and tried using '+' to concatenate the string like how it works in other languages, and when I use this

```
writeln("ERROR: \""  + Head +  "\" is invalid.")
```

I almost succeed in what I want, and it prints

```
ERROR: " + a + " is invalid.
```

with the variable 'a' highlighted (another requirement) when I am trying to get

```
ERROR: "a" is invalid.
```

But I am unable to print it without using characters such as +, -, or | to contain the variable. I don't really understand what is going on and I haven't been able to find a reason on my own.

Using string_concat twice makes the proper string, but the variable is not highlighted like it is supposed to be.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to concatenate two atoms/strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16898156/how-to-concatenate-two-atoms-strings)

Comment: I tested it and using string_concat twice would work, but the argument won't be highlighted, and I believe it should be done within writeln. I am also trying to figure out why the + is appearing in the string.

Comment: @Jonny `?- write_canonical("ERROR: \""  + Head +  "\" is invalid.").` will show you that it is not a string, it is a *term* like this: `+(+("ERROR: \"",_),"\" is invalid.")`.

Comment: Consider `format/2`.

Answer (score 0):

As you already mentioned, using string_concat solves your problem as you want. String concatenation does not work like this in Prolog as it does in different languages. The reason why it still prints something when using the + while it throws without it is that the + is in an infix operator and is displayed as such in when using writeln because it also writes out the predicate names.

It will write the + infix when provided as prefix such as in this example:

`writeln(+(3,2)).`

It does not work without the + because then you simply have three different values after another. Quoted Atom, Variable filled with an Atom, Quoted Atom. Prolog expects a term though, so you run into a syntax error.